# Convert old JavaScript code into ES6 module

Tags: javascript, es6-module-loader

I'm trying to convert an old JavaScript library into ES6 compatible module.
The library is tracking.js (https://github.com/eduardolundgren/tracking.js/blob/master/build/tracking.js) but all my results ends with: `Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined`

Is there any easy way to use such module? I'm trying to create just basic example like https://trackingjs.com/docs.html#step-2

## Update

Because there is a request for more code. Let me show one of the non-working examples (part of Vue.js component):

```
import tracking from 'tracking';

export default {
  created() {
    const colors = new tracking.ColorTracker(['magenta', 'cyan', 'yellow']);
  }
};
```

And the error is `TypeError: _tracking2.default.ColorTracker is not a constructor`

Comment: But, put some code, explain more

Comment: @pmirnd here you are. Still it is totally wrong, but I don't know how should I start :(

Comment: Normally this would be the job of the module loader. For example webpack and SystemJS have options to consume scripts that add themselves to the global scope (as tracking.js does). What are you using to load the ES6 module?

Comment: @user3432422 I'm using webpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [exports-loader](https://github.com/webpack/exports-loader), no modification of the library is necessary, the loader will look for the variable on the global scope, e.g.:

```
import * as tracking from 'exports-loader?tracking!tracking';
```

The exports-loader needs to know how to access the module on the global scope (tracking.js assigns itself to `window.tracking`). Here you're telling it to use the exports-loader with parameter `tracking` (after the query question mark) to load the module `tracking` (after the exclamation mark).

Comment: syntax changed (`import * as tracking from 'exports-loader?tracking!tracking';`) but it is working

Comment: Ah yeah I forgot about that, thanks. Updated answer.

Comment: The question remains, however, for those of us using native module support in all modern browsers except chrome which will land soon. So how do we do as asked: convert an existing library to an es6 module? Possibly build a wrapper of some sort?