# Computer-Vision with React

Tags: reactjs, computer-vision, webrtc, getusermedia, tracking.js

I'm trying to find a client-side computer-vision library that plays nicely with React. I've tried tracking.js and js-objectdetect but I can't import them into a standard React component without major efforts that are beyond my skills.

The problem with both these awesome libraries is that they are written as IIFE with no export statements e.g.

`(function(){...})()`

They are supposed to be imported as `<script src = 'etc'>` so I can't seem to just `import` them as normal and follow the API without getting

`TypeError: foo.bah is not a constructor`

I tried adding my own export statements but a can of worms exploded out of it!

Can anyone suggest a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack you can try [exports-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/exports-loader) to allow you using import syntax.

Here is some more [info](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html#exporting).

Comment: Fantastic - I found the same solution here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42649796/convert-old-javascript-code-into-es6-module

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working implementation of tracking.js with React (using create-react-app)

https://github.com/howardkitto/react-tracking

The solution was provided by https://github.com/gaearon, here... https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2958