# Including javascript with global var into typescript module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'd like to include a JS library (hwcrypto.js) into a Angular/Typescript module, but i'm little bit confused about how this could be done.
The main file has a global variable declaration

```
var hwcrypto = ...
```

i've tried in this ways, but no ones worked

```
import * as hwcrypto from 'hwcrypto-js/hwcrypto.js'
```

```
const hwcrypto = require('hwcrypto-js/hwcrypto.js')
```

How should i do?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on how `hwcrypto.js` is being exported (if at all)

Comment: There's no export... the library is used as a global variable window.hwcrypto

Comment: Maybe this can be of help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42649796/convert-old-javascript-code-into-es6-module

Comment: include script in angular.json scripts and in .ts file `declare const hwcrypto : any;` ?

Comment: There are also typing https://www.npmjs.com/package/hwcrypto-ts